# How to replace element in MeshRenderer.sharedMaterials

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We are using a object from the asset store that makes usage's of a mesh renderer with 32 materials in it. We need to implement functionality that makes it possible to replace 1 single material in the list, and keep the rest.

I have tried several things, but I keep struggeling with the materials list, that is why I decided to ask you guys for help.

```
public Material TestMaterial;

void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < meshRenderer.sharedMaterials.Length; i++)
    {
        if (meshRenderer.sharedMaterials[i].name == "replaceableMat")
        {
            // Replace with TestMaterial
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is how I kinda want to use it.

The TestMaterial object is not null, it is selected from the Unity Editor, so that is fine.

Could someone give me some insight?

Thanks in forward!

Answer (score 6):

from [`Renderer.sharedMaterials`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterials.html):

> Note that like all arrays returned by Unity, this returns a copy of materials array. If you want to change some materials in it, get the value, change an entry and set materials back.

---

You have to do exactly that. Store the materials in a temporary variable, change entries and write the entire array back to `sharedMaterials` when done:

```
var materials = meshRenderer.sharedMaterials;
for(int i = 0; i < materials.Length; i++)
{
    if(!string.Equals(materials[i].name, "replaceableMat") continue;

    materials[i] = TestMaterial;
}
meshRenderer.sharedMaterials = materials;
```

---

The reason in the background is that `sharedMaterials` is not a *field* but a **property**.

Since the assignment of `sharedMaterial[i]` is not an assignment to the whole property what it does is just replacing that entry in a temporary array but not actually assigning it back to the `Renderer` component.

Only by assigning a value to the entire property actually makes the property execute it's setter and writes the array back to the `Renderer` component.

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < meshRenderer.sharedMaterials.Length; i++)
        {
            if (meshRenderer.sharedMaterials[i].name == "replaceableMat")
            {
                // Replace with TestMaterial
                renderer.sharedMaterials[i] = TestMaterial

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No it won't! See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55852872/7111561)